# PHP mail headers problem

Tags: php

I'm trying to use BCC fields in some PHP email.  My code is as below:

```
    $to = "myemail@email.com";
$subject = 'Subject here';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <myemail@email.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: <myemail@email.com>\r\n";
//send the email
if (!mail($to, $subject, 'body', $headers)){
    echo "Error";
}
```

What I've discovered is that if I include the bcc field in my headers the script just errors and the email is not sent. I've looked everywhere for the syntax and my understanding is that what I have is correct, but clearly something is wrong! Thanks

Comment: Are you on `Win` or `*nix`. `Win` have some pequliar features that might cause this bug, see [notes section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CC and BCC headers when using php's mail() function are blocked by the suhosin security module.

I found this in: http://forums.asmallorange.com/topic/11501-php-mail-cc-bcc-headers/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at this.  I'll look into the alternatives!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it, works for me

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/12908.php

check your mailserver

Answer (score 0):

What line is the error on. Maybe it's good to use all double quotes or all single quotes also, and not mixed up. You can also remove the concat dot in the MIME line.